# Realistic chrome effect with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm trying to archive a sharper and more realistic chrome effect.
The granularity in my demo is really rough and pixilated. 
What are the options to get a perfect smooth mirror effect on a custom object?

[image]

```
     var path = "textures/reflection/";
      var format = '.jpg';

      var urls = [
          path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
          path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
          path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
      ];

  var envMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls, THREE.CubeReflectionMapping );

  var chrome = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
      color: 0xffffff,
      specular:0xffffff,
      envMap: envMap,
      combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation,
      shininess: 50,
      reflectivity: 1.0
  } );
```

Comment: what is the size of your environment textures?

Comment: 1024x1024 px. Sharp images

Comment: It looks like the normals of your object aren't set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the cube texture with a function within the shader to get very clean edges, but this is not a trivial task if you've never written a shader before.

If you have, then just use the same 3D reflection vector that you'd apply to the 3D texture lookup, but instead use a cut-off function, typically based on y, something like

```
reflVec = normalize(reflVec);
vec3 reflectColor = (reflVec.y > 0.3) ? vec3(1,1,1) : vec3(0,0,0);
```

...within the shader code. There would be some tiny aliasing here but it would be very very sharp. Anti-aliasing is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow quick answer. If you're using FXAA or the like you might not even see the aliasing.